# Basic Cron job to run a shell script to append date in a log, not working

Tags: linux, macos, shell, cron

I have a **`addlog.sh`** file which has the following content:

```sh
echo "time right now:" `date` >> ~/Desktop/date.log
```

This is how my `crontab -l` looks like:

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /Users/naman/Desktop/addlog.sh
```

I have added correct permissions to `addlog.sh` file and my shell is at `/bin/sh`. 
I have verified that the manual run of `addlog.sh` is appending time to the `date.log` file.

I am running this in my local Mac. But its not working and not sure what I might be missing here.

Comment: Works for me on 10.11.  What version of macOS do you have?  Have a look at `/var/log/system.log` to see if it has any relevant log messages.

Comment: the reason as pointed by @rtx13 is with the version of Mac. Solution 1 suggested by him already works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are running Catalina (10.15) with its restrictive system integrity protection. There are two possible solutions.

### Solution 1

Move your script and log file out of `~/Desktop` into `~/`.  In contrast to `~/Desktop`, `~/Documents`, and may other folders, the home directory is not subject to system integrity protection.

### Solution 2

If you need to keep your script and logfile under `~/Desktop`:

1. Add `#!/bin/sh` shebang (first line) to your `addlog.sh` script
2. Make a trivial `addlog.app` from your `addlog.sh` script as follows:

```
mkdir -p ~/Desktop/addlog.app/Resources/MacOS/
cp ~/Desktop/addlog.sh ~/Desktop/addlog.app/Resources/MacOS/addlog
chmod +x ~/Desktop/addlog.app/Resources/MacOS/addlog
```

3. Change your `crontab` to the following:

```
* * * * * /Users/naman/Desktop/addlog.app/Resources/MacOS/addlog
```

You also have to allow the newly created app access to files in SIP-protected areas, as follows:

1. Open 'System Preferences', 'Security & Privacy'
2. Click on the padlock and authenticate to make changes.
3. Select 'Full Disk Access' in the left pane.
4. On the right-hand side click `+`.
5. Navigate to Desktop and select your new app `addlog`. It will be added to the list of apps. Ensure that the checkmark is selected.
6. Close 'System Preferences'

Comment: Solution 2 also worked but I had to keep the log file also at a non-Desktop location for the shell script to input in that log file. Can you @rtx13 help me understand the need for using .app here

Comment: Actually there may be more steps involved for solution 2.  I'll add some more detail shortly...

Comment: The new steps, looked like, should have worked. But somehow didn't. But that's not an important step as I was just using this for my learning and the Step 1 itself has helped me and Step 2 with a little change. Thanks anyways for helping way beyond.

Comment: You're welcome.  For reference can you confirm which version of macOS you are running?

Comment: I am using macOS Catalina ver 10.15.4